# Assigning rowkey values in Azure table storage

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

I want to store my users in an Azure table. My preference is to use Integer values as UserId's. How can I generate unique UserId's (integer values) before saving user information in an Azure table?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to avoid generating a unique id in terms maintaining the state. This is due to the fact that there is lot of work involved on resolving potential concurrency issues. You could consider using GUID for this purpose.